# Derivative of an Infinitesimal?

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, infinitesimals, euler-lagrange-equation

I am currently studying calculus of variations (for my classical mechanics course). I have, on multiple occasions, seen the derivative of an infinitesimal quantity defined like below
$$\frac{d}{dt} \delta  q(t)=\delta \frac{dq(t)}{dt}$$

Now, I do have a geometrical intuition about how this works. By changing a trajectory $q(t)$ between two time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$ by  $\delta q(t)$ , I understand it is natural that the derivatives of $q(t)$ will also change, which is reflected in the formula given above. But I do not understand how this equality comes about in a rigorous sense.

Any insight would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give enough detail to explain what the context of your formula is, but if $\delta$ is supposed to be a constant infinitesimal, then the formula you wrote down is correct by the [transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle#Transfer_principle_for_the_hyperreals), since it is true for any real value of $\delta$.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need infinitesimals to do calculus of variations. Simply consider adding a finite quantity,
$$\delta q(t) = \epsilon \gamma(t),$$
where $\gamma(t)$ is some curve and $\epsilon$ is a small positive number which may be sent to zero later on.

Whilst it is possible to define infinitesimals in a way that makes them rigorous -- it's a not very popular field called "non-standard analysis" and I think few people on this forum will use them.

Comment: There's another way to make infinitesimals consistent - smooth infinitesimal analysis, which is different from non-standard analysis.